# When is the Hom-scheme connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes, representable-functors

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two algebras finite over a field $K$ (which may be assumed to be separably closed, if that helps), then we know that the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_K(\mathrm{Spec}(A),\mathrm{Spec}(B))$ from $(\mathbf{Sch}/K)$ to $(\mathbf{Sets})$, defined by 
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_K(\mathrm{Spec}(A),\mathrm{Spec}(B))(T):=\mathrm{Hom}_T(\mathrm{Spec}(A)\times_K T, \mathrm{Spec}(B)\times_K T),$$
is represented by an open subscheme $U$ of $\mathrm{Hilb}(\mathrm{Spec}(A)\times_K \mathrm{Spec}(B)/K)$.

Do we know when $U$ is connected? Thanks!

Comment: No, your functor is not representable by a scheme, already e.g. for $A=B=k[X]$.

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny Sorry, I meant, algebras finite over $K$. I have corrected my question. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I like this question. When A and B are (truncated) infinitesimal neighborhoods of a smooth point, then $Hom$ will be connected (in fact, it will be iso to some $\mathbb{A}^M$). But, at non-singular points, explicit computations show that the space will often not be irreducible (yet remain connected). Off the top of my head at the moment, I cannot think of an example where $Hom$ is disconnected. The same question may be asked for non finite algebras, if you are willing to work with formal schemes.

Comment: @AndrewStout: Thank you! Indeed the singular case is where the problem is. I suspect that there is an example where it is disconnected. Yet, it would also be useful if it turns out to be connected for all finite algebras.

Comment: oh, I thought of a trivial example: $Hom_k(spec(k), spec(k) \sqcup spec(k)) $. I think $A$ and $B$ should local artinian rings with residue field $k$ (or at least a finite extension of $k$). Then, I truly do not know of example having worked with such things for a few years.

Comment: Whether or not you assume commutativity, you won't in general get connectivity. Take for example maps from the n'th neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$ into the n'th neighborhood of $0$ in $Spec(k[x,y]/(xy)$. These mapping spaces are in general at least as complicated as mapping spaces of fixed degree between projective varieties: if $A$ is functions on a neighborhood of the affine cone of a projective variety $X$ and $B$ is functions in a neighborhood of 0 in a veronese twisted affine cone of $Y$ then $Map(B,A)$ goes to $Map(X,Y)$ surjectively by taking blowups of tangent cones.

Comment: @DmitryVaintrob: I do not quite agree with your example, although I agree with the spirit of what you say.  The natural $\mathbb{G}_m$-action on $\text{Spec}(B)$ will induce a $\mathbb{G}_m$-action on the Hom scheme.  If you remove the vertex and form the quotient by this $\mathbb{G}_m$-action, I believe you get the situation that you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only just noticed this question.  I agree with Andrew Stout, but I am afraid that I disagree with Dmitry Vaintrob.  To make Dmitry's example precise, assume $B$ is a graded, Artinian (commutative, unital) $K$-algebra with residue field $K$, i.e., $$B = B_0 \oplus \dots \oplus B_q \oplus \dots \oplus B_n,$$ where $B_0 = K$.  This is the case, for instance, if we take $\text{Spec}(B)$ to be the infinitesimal neighborhood of the vertex in an affine cone with nilpotency index $n$.

There is a distinguished graded $K$-algebra homomorphism, $$ z : B \to A,\ \ z(b_0) = b_0,\ \ z(b_q) = 0,\  q > 0.$$  Moreover, there is a graded $K$-algebra homomorphism, $$ \mu^*: B[T] \to B[T], \ \ \mu^*(b_qT^d) = b_qT^{d+q}.$$  For any $K$-algebra homomorphism, $w:B\to A$, define the associated $K$-algebra homomorphism $w\otimes \text{Id}_{K[T]}$ as follows, $$ w\otimes \text{Id}_{K[T]} : B[T] \to A[T], \ \ (w\otimes\text{Id}_{K[T]})(bT^d) = w(b)T^d. $$  Now consider the composite $K$-algebra homomorphism, $$\widetilde{w}:B[T]\to A[T], \ \ \widetilde{w} = (w\otimes \text{Id}_{K[T]})\circ \mu^*.$$  When we specialize $\widetilde{w}$ via evaluation at $T=1$, then we recover $w$.  However, when we specialize via evaluation at $T=0$, we get the "vertex" $z$.  Interpreted differently, $\widetilde{w}$ gives a $K$-morphism, $$\widetilde{w}:\mathbb{A}^1_K \to \text{Hom}_K(\text{Spec}(A),\text{Spec}(B)),$$ that sends $1$ to $w$ and sends $0$ to the vertex $z$.  Thus the Hom scheme is representable by a connected $K$-scheme when $B$ is graded and Artinian.